# Merge/join two big files

Tags: java, c, join, awk, merge

I have 2 files that i would like to join on the first column :
file 1 contains 46395029 lines and file 2 contains 86510559.

file1.txt

```
>ID sequence
CJP75M1:393:C2T21ACXX:8:1101:2069:1997 1:N:0:_45    TAGTATTACGACG
CJP75M1:393:C2T21ACXX:8:1101:2711:1992 1:N:0:_65    TCCGAGGCCCTGTAATTGGAATGAGTAC
CJP75M1:393:C2T21ACXX:8:1101:3822:1989 1:N:0:_115   CCGGAGAGGGAGCCTGAGAAACGGCTACCAC
```

file2.txt

```
>ID      Barcode
CJP75M1:393:C2T21ACXX:8:1101:2069:1997 1:N:0:_45    CTCG
CJP75M1:393:C2T21ACXX:8:1101:2711:1992 1:N:0:_65        CTAG
CJP75M1:393:C2T21ACXX:8:1101:3822:1989 1:N:0:_115       CTGG
```

I would like to merge these two files on the first colum to have :

```
>TAGTATTACGACG    CTCG
TCCGAGGCCCTGTAATTGGAATGAGTAC     CTAG
CCGGAGAGGGAGCCTGAGAAACGGCTACCAC     CTGG
```

In only want lines in file1 so result file should contain "only" 46395029 lines.
I did it with awk :

```
    awk 'BEGIN {FS= "\t"; OFS="\t"} { while (getline < "file1.txt") { f[$1] = $2} {print $2, f[$1] }}' "file2.txt" | sed '1d' > result.txt
```

But it's really long (2 days it is running). I have a linux debian (stable) server of 64bit / 16Go of RAM

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: Are the "keys" ordered in some way in the files?

Comment: By curiosity, why the java tag and C tag?

Comment: No they are not. In fact, in file 2 i have all IDs, whereas in file 1 this is a subset

Comment: Because i am open to any suggestion in any langage !

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way with `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==1{next}NR==FNR{map[$1,$2]=$3;next}(map[$1,$2]){print map[$1,$2],$3}' file2 file1
```

- Skip first lines from both files
- create an array indexed at column 1 and 2 from file2
- If map exists in file1 print the line

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in Java (7+) -- you asked for it :)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;

public final class Job
{
    private static final Pattern PATTERN
        = Pattern.compile("(\\S+\\s+\\S+)\\s+(.*)");

    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException
    {
        final Map<String, String> fromFile1 = new HashMap<>();

        final Charset charset = StandardCharsets.US_ASCII;
        final Path file1 = Paths.get("/tmp/f1.txt");
        final Path file2 = Paths.get("/tmp/f2.txt");
        final Path dstfile = Paths.get("/tmp/dst.txt");
        Matcher m;
        String line, key, value;
        StringBuilder sb;

        // Lines from file 1
        try (
            final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file1,
                charset);
        ) {
            reader.readLine();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                m = PATTERN.matcher(line);
                if (m.matches())
                    fromFile1.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
            }
        }

        // Write in destination file
        try (
            final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file2,
                charset);
            final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(dstfile,
                charset, CREATE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
        ) {
            reader.readLine();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                m = PATTERN.matcher(line);
                if (!m.matches())
                    continue;
                key = m.group(1);
                value = fromFile1.get(key);
                if (value == null)
                    continue;
                sb = new StringBuilder(value).append('\t')
                    .append(m.group(2)).append('\n');
                writer.write(sb.toString());
            }
            writer.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Put this in a file named `Job.java`. To compile, you need a JDK 7+, and:

```
javac Job.java
```

To execute, you'll need quite some memory, so:

```
java -Xmx4G Job
```

Change the paths as appropriate, of course!

---

Note that if you have to manipulate such files often, I'd suggest you make the lines fixed-length if at all possible; the treatment will then be much faster. Or even maybe use a database engine?

Comment: You just killed a tiny ant with bazooka!! Damn!! `:)`

Comment: @jaypal meh, if the treatment takes hours, you can spare a few minutes writing some custom code ;)

Comment: I can't vouch for correctness, but this effort deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

The `join` command may be what you need: `join` requires the input files to be sorted on the join field though

```
join -o 1.3,2.3 -a 1 -e "??" <(sed 1d file1.txt | sort -k1,1) <(sed 1d file2.txt | sort -k1,1)
```

Which produces, given your sample data:

```
CGGACGTGATCACTGTGACGCCTTGCGTGTTACGGTTGTT CNCG
TAGTATTACGACG AGGC
TCCGAGGCCCTGTAATTGGAATGAGTAC ??
CCGGAGAGGGAGCCTGAGAAACGGCTACCAC ??join -o 1.3,2.3 -a 1 -e "??" <(sed 1d file1.txt | sort -k1,1) <(sed 1d file2.txt | sort -k1,1)
TTGGAGGGC ??
TTGATGGTAGTATC ??
AATAAAACGATGCATTTATGTATTTTTGATT ??
TCCTCGATAGTATAGTGGTTAGTATCCCCGCC ??
TGATGGTAGTATC ??
```

With this much data, I think your best bet would be to import your data into a relational database (such as [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/)) and produce the report with SQL.

Comment: Yes i try it, it's running since 2 hours ... I don't know if it is normal. I use sqlite with python